# How to create Set from Pydblite in Python

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, duplicates

Hello i'm using PyDbLite in order to store Url in a Python database.
My script add urls any time in database but i want to delete duplicate (or make a Set) keeping only one same Url at the ending of the program.

I have only two fields Url and Date:

```
    self.db = Base('URL_database.pdl')
    self.db.create('url', 'date', mode="open")
```